# How do you convert a string into base64 in .net framework 4

Tags: vb.net, string

So I've been going around the internet looking for a way to convert regular text(string) into base64 string and found many solutions. I'm trying to use:

```
Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
TextBox2.Text = convert.ToBase64String(byt)
```

but it end up with an error saying

> 'ToBase64String' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer'.

What do I do to fix this? Or if there's a better way to code it please help.

Comment: So you have a timer on your form, named `convert`?

Comment: @MarkChai, Yes...  That's what the error message says.

Comment: @Brad omg im such a dork. I havent done vb in a month and this is what hppens. thanks man

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `System.Convert.ToBase64String(byt)`. Otherwise the timer is picked up as the innermost matching name.
<sub>Not the best name for a timer btw.</sub>

Comment: Haha Thanks, I might use this code. But I figured I might name the timer to convert since I'll be converting into binary and hex.